# Sending a pre-written in-app user notification to other users in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How could I send a pre-written in-app user notification to other users in my Firebase? I just want whichever user cell I tap on in my tableview to receive the same pre-written notification.

I have also enabled notifications in the AppDelegate.

I am aware of Firebase push notification, that is not necessarily what I am going for, I want the notifications to be triggered by other users, from the tableview.

Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

class NewMessageController: UITableViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

let cellId = "cellId"

var users = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3, 0, 11);
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "People"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.22, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    fetchUser()
}

func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"]as? String
            self.users.append(user)

            //this will crash because of background thread, so lets use dispatch_async to fix
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

            //                user.name = dictionary["name"]
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}

@objc func handleCancel() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.email
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}

//var messagesController: MessagesController?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let messi = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    messi.title = "HelloApp"
    messi.body = "Hi There!"
    messi.badge = 1
    messi.categoryIdentifier = "messiCategory"


    let messiTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)

    let messiRequestIdentifier = "messi"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: messiRequestIdentifier, content: messi, trigger: messiTrigger)


    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in

        print(error as Any)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onesignal,it is free and can work in firebase 
You send device to device or devices or device to  segmentsnotification  in app with swift
It can work by this model:
Use onesignal sdk to get a user specific id,when creating an account ,save it in firebase like this
Your database
-Users-
     - UserId
              -OnesignalId: “the id created by onesignal function”
Then when want to send a notification to the above user from a different user
It can be used like this
This is a function by onesignal SDK
OneSignal.postNotification([“heading”:[en:” what you want”],”contents”: “thecontenthere”],”include_player_ids”: OnsignalID)
This send a notification from a device to device that have this onesignalID